# how to sum model in Django rest Api

Tags: python, django, api

**I am new to Django rest API development I want to sum rent_amount, bijli_bill, other_amount and get value as Total amount, I don't know to add them pls help**

*I want value like this*

> {
> "id": 1,
> "rent_date": "23-08-2022",
> "rentmonth": "June",
> "rent_amount": 500.0,
> "bijli_bill": 200.0,
> "other_amount": 100.0,
> "other_commnet": "test",
> "total_amount": 800.0,
> }
>
> *This the model file*
>
> from sqlite3 import Date from django.db import models from django
> import forms from django.contrib.auth.models import User

```py
class rent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rent_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    rentmonth = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rent_amount = models.FloatField()
    bijli_bill = models.FloatField()
    other_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    other_commnet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)
```

*This is my serializer*

> from rest_framework import serializers from .models import rent from
> django.contrib.auth.models import User from django.db.models import
> Sum

```py
class rentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rent_date = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", read_only=True)
    rentmonth = serializers.CharField()
    rent_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    bijli_bill = serializers.FloatField()
    other_amount = serializers.FloatField()
    other_commnet = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
 

    class Meta:
        model = rent
        fields = ('__all__')
```

*This is view file*

> class rentViews(APIView):
>
> ```
> def get(self, request, id=None):
>     if id:
>         item = rent.objects.get(id=id)
>         serializer = rentSerializer(item)
>         return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
>
>     items = rent.objects.all()
>     serializer = rentSerializer(items, many=True)
>     return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
> ```

Comment: What are the issues you're currently facing? 
Also, what do you want if an 'id' is not passed?
It is always a good idea to return a single object from a detailed API

Comment: I just want when sum of three model in get method ( rent_amount , bijli_bill & other amount ) Like Total amount = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Property to your Django model that is called `total_cost` for example

```py
class rent(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rent_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    rentmonth = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rent_amount = models.FloatField()
    bijli_bill = models.FloatField()
    other_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    other_commnet = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200)

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.rent_amount + self.bijli_bill + self.other_amount
```

now you can get `total_cost` like any other variable

```py
rentExample = rent.objects.create(User=user, rentmonth="02", rent_amount=30, bijli_bill=30, other_amount=30)

print(rentExample.total_cost)
# output: 90
```

Comment: Not working after calling get method i didnot get anything

Comment: @PunitKumar I have tested the code, it's working perfectly fine could you give more details on how you're calling the get method

Comment: @PunitKumar add `total_cost = serializers.FloatField()` to your serializer also

Comment: Yes Thankyou after adding total_cost in Serializers it works